# Can´t Disable Free Shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

We are having an issue with Magento. Randomly this week it started only displaying free shipping. We don't offer free shipping.

It's disabled on the backend and there are no rules allowing for it. We use matrixrates to calculate the rates.

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: If you use Matrix rates, the problem will lie within there. Is the "Free Shipping Promotions" setting set to be disabled? And underneath it "only show free shipping" should be set to no.

Comment: Can you export your Matrix Rates configuration to show us some more detail? You can also reach out to WebShopApps for support if their extension does not seem to behave as intended.